# How can depend on a PlayProject in GitHub?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I want to have a Play 2.0 project depend on another Play 2.0 project and I want it to checkout and build that project when it builds.

I know how I could do this if the dependent project was not a PlayProject, but a standard library.  I could use something like this.

```
val libDep = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/ChazInc/play2-authenticitytoken.git"))

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  // settings here
).dependsOn(libDep)
```

That won't work for me with the play project since I need the special build logic I get for free from a PlayProject for the dependency.  I see that PlayProject can take a file argument, but it doesn't take a URI arguement like RootProject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a git project directly, the project in question must have a `project` folder with `Build.scala` and/or `plugins.sbt` at the root level of the project. It sucks for Play modules, but that's the way it currently is.

Comment: Thanks, that was a start, not it is finding sources.  There is still something wrong.  I'm seeing this awful error popping up now.  Seems to be a bug in SBT from what I've found on the nets.


[info] Loading project definition from /home/myyk/.sbt/staging/29d5c45ee06bc7355fb9/project
[error] AttributeKey ID collisions detected for: 'eclipse-projectTransformerFactory' scala.collection.Seq[com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.EclipsePlugin$@5b8b0b4a.type#com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core.EclipsePlugin$EclipseTransformerFactory[scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule]] ...\